# The sample of FQL query in FB is incorrect. Someone has a correct sample?

Tags: sql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The sample posted in the documentation, at:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/
is incorrect and does not work. (php)

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
. '/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()'
. '&' . $access_token;
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
```

=> there are two / : ...facebook.com//fql...
=> the word "&access_token" is missing.

However, even issuing the correct url, the function does not seem to return anything...
Here is the code I have been using:
(function is passed $id, like 12345678)

```
$Fb = new Facebook(array('appId'=>FB_API_ID,'secret'=>FB_API_SECRET));
$access_token = $Fb->getAccessToken();
$fql_query_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=".$id."&access_token=" . $access_token;
$resp = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$var = json_decode($resp, true);
$txt .= "<br /><b>FQL QUERY:</b><br />" . display_tree($var);
```

Someone made it???

Answer (score 0):

This query seems to work for me when I run it in the browser. Are you sure you have a valid access token?

Can you try it from the Graph API Explorer? Here's the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%3Dme%28%29).

Comment: You have actually corrected the initial code of the sample, removing the double slash and adding the access_token!

Comment: Indeed, ran through the graph api (after getting and access token), YOUR copy works, but you have corrected the sample.

Comment: Fair enough on the sample, but you also said you couldn't get the API to return anything - I was responding more to that.

Comment: I'll report the sample bug to the Facebook doc writers.

Comment: Agreed!  Ran through the Explorer: returns an exception: permission denied: can only look for the logged in user, or with permissions given.  So, I'll check the perms... Thanks for your quick help (I'll be back!!!)

Comment: Looking at the sample again, you are correct that there's a double slash, but I don't think that matters. I put in the URL with the double slash into the browser and it still works fine. The access_token part is actually correct. If you look at what is returned from the access_token endpoint, it is actually a string that includes the "access_token=" part. So the variable $access_token is set to the value "$access_token=..." where ... is the actual access token value. So it's fine to just concatenate it onto the string. See See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for details.